# Black Diamond cheddar, wedge not wheel

Tags: cheese, food-identification

I bought some Black Diamond cheddar today and it came in a large wedge of black wax. By large I mean it was maybe 12" x 8" x 8" thick. A really big wedge. Also, it looked like it was not cut from a wheel, but was actually aged in a wedge-shaped form.

I went to the Black Diamond web site to find out what kind of cheddar it was, but I could not find it described on the web site (they only had the cheap supermarket-style cheeses on their web site, not the premium cheeses).

Does anybody know what kind of reserve this might have been? 5 year, 10 year, what?

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have figured it out. They seem to have a product called Grand Reserve Triad, or something like that which is a 2-year cheddar:

[image]